# Can a windows 8 metro tile have different clickable regions with different outcomes?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro

hopefully a quick question,

is it possible to have a live tile that has several clickable regions in it (on display at the same time)?

thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can, and it would sort of go against the [recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx) (simplicity and uniform look between tiles). "Tiles are based on a non-extensible set of Windows-provided XML templates" [Guidelines and checklist for tiles (Metro style apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx)

If you want to display additional information/different information then maybe [secondary tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465372.aspx) maybe is an option for you?

What would you like to do?

Good luck with your project, hope this helped :)

Comment: what i am trying to do is have a tile launch two different apps from the same family dependent on where it is clicked.